# Acumular valores en array

Tags: php

Este array es lo que quiero conseguir

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 45704
            [importe] => 340
            [acumulado] => 340  <-- INCREMENTAR CON CADA [importe]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 45986
            [importe] => 400.00
            [acumulado] => 740  <-- INCREMENTADO
        )

)
```

Estoy tratando de totalizar en cada [acumulado] la suma de los [importe]

```
$acumulado = 0;
foreach ($arreglo as $k => $row) {
    $arreglo[$k]['acumulado'] = $acumulado + $arreglo[$k]['importe'];
}
```

Pero solo me muestra el mismo valor de importe.
Qué es lo que está faltando?

Comment: Quizá porque `$acumulado` siempre es cero, ya que solo lo lees pero no no le estás sumando valor alguno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar cambiar la estructura del foreach por lo siguiente:

```
    $acumulado = 0;
    foreach ($arreglo as $k => $row) {
    // Primero sumamos el importe actual al valor acumulado
    $acumulado += $row['importe'];

    // Luego asignamos el valor acumulado al elemento 'acumulado' del array
    $arreglo[$k]['acumulado'] = $acumulado;
}
```

Con este código, en cada iteración del bucle foreach, se sumará el valor del elemento ***importe*** al valor ***acumulado***, y luego se asignará el valor ***acumulado*** al elemento ***acumulado*** del array.